# convert (void *) to (SInt16 *) to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert the following from Objective-C to Swift:

```
-(int)fillBuffer:(void *)buffer {
  SInt16* p = (SInt16 *)buffer;

  // ...

  p[33] = 0
}
```

I've come to understand that `(void *)` maps to the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?` type in Swift.

However, I'm missing a step in converting it into something that can take the subscript operation.

So far, I've got this:

```
func fill(buffer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!) -> Int {
  buffer[33] = 0
}
```

Looking for feedback and advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting a void pointer to a typed pointer

```
SInt16* p = (SInt16 *)buffer;
```

is done in Swift with `assumingMemoryBound()`:

```
func fillBuffer(_ buffer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> Int {
    let p = buffer.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self)
    // ...
    p[33] = 0
    return 0
}
```

Test code:

```
var i16Array = Array(repeating: Int16(99), count: 40)
print(i16Array[33]) // 99
_ = fillBuffer(&i16Array) // passes a pointer to the element storage to the function
print(i16Array[33]) // 0
```